# When property is used as decorator, the setter does not raise the exception

Tags: python, exception, properties, decorator, setter

I am learning Python and there is one weird thing happening with *@property* which I don't understand...

I found an example [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) on how property works and I found it pretty clear. 
The following code works fine:

```py
class Celsius:

    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def to_farenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")  # just to see on screen when we call it
        return self._temperature

    def set_temperature(self, value):
        print("Setting value")  # just to see on screen when we call it
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature cannot be less than -273 °C !")
        self._temperature = value

    temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)
```

When we try to set a temperature below absolute zero, we see that the setter is called and the ValueError is raised:

```py
T = Celsius(-400)
```

```
>>> Setting value
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>> ...
>>> ValueError: Temperature cannot be less than -273 °C !
```

However, when we define property as a decorator (i.e. *@property*) as in the code below:

```py
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        print("Setting value")
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value
```

And we do the same thing, the setter is not called and the exception is not raised:

```py
T = Celsius(-400)
print(T.temperature)
```

```
>>> Getting value
>>> -400
```

It looks like *@temperature.setter* is never called, even when we change the value of T :

```py
T = Celsius(20)
print(T.temperature)
```

```
>>> Getting value
>>> -400
```

I don't understand... can someone explain it to me ?

Comment: In your `__init__`, change `self._temperature = temperature` to `self.temperature = temperature`.

Comment: In your first example, `__init__` uses your setter. In your second example, it does not. There is no implicit connection between `_temperature` and `temperature`, other than the fact that the names are chosen to suggest one. `temperature` is the name of a property which makes use of another attribute named `_temperature`.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo, although the distinction between a property and an "ordinary" attribute may warrant an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class initilizer you are setting input `temperature` as instance attribute `_temperature`, but you have property getter and setter for attribute `temperature`.

In current form, if you were to set attribure `temperature`, you would get the desired exception:

```
In [505]: c = Celsius(-400)                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [506]: c.temperature                                                                                                                                                                                     
Getting value
Out[506]: -400

In [507]: c.temperature = -500                                                                                                                                                                              
Setting value
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-507-2b9ed72eeb52> in <module>
----> 1 c.temperature = -500

<ipython-input-504-e44aad21660f> in temperature(self, value)
     15         print("Setting value")
     16         if value < -273:
---> 17             raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
     18         print("Setting value")
     19         self._temperature = value

ValueError: Temperature below -273 is not possible
```

There you go.

Now, if you change yor `__init__` to set the input `temperature` as `temperature` attribute, you would get the exception while initilizing the class:

```
In [508]: class Celsius: 
     ...:     def __init__(self, temperature = 0): 
     ...:         self.temperature = temperature 
     ...:  
     ...:     def to_fahrenheit(self): 
     ...:         return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32 
     ...:  
     ...:     @property 
     ...:     def temperature(self): 
     ...:         print("Getting value") 
     ...:         return self.temperature 
     ...:  
     ...:     @temperature.setter 
     ...:     def temperature(self, value): 
     ...:         print("Setting value") 
     ...:         if value < -273: 
     ...:             raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible") 
     ...:         print("Setting value") 
     ...:         self.temperature = value 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [509]: c = Celsius(-400)                                                                                                                                                                                 
Setting value
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-509-1fc014754084> in <module>
----> 1 c = Celsius(-400)

<ipython-input-508-af8466917803> in __init__(self, temperature)
      1 class Celsius:
      2     def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
----> 3         self.temperature = temperature
      4 
      5     def to_fahrenheit(self):

<ipython-input-508-af8466917803> in temperature(self, value)
     15         print("Setting value")
     16         if value < -273:
---> 17             raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
     18         print("Setting value")
     19         self.temperature = value

ValueError: Temperature below -273 is not possible
```

---

**Why your first code works?**

In your first code, you've set attribute `temperature` as the input `temperature` value in `__init__`.

Due to the use of `property` callable (which is a descriptor), python sees that you have a descriptor `temperature` and it's a data descriptor as you have a setter as well. So it tries to invoke the setter method to set the value.